# React & WebStorm - Expression expected

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following code:

```
'use strict';

import {LocalizationTextType} from 'spio';

import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';

import SimpleFlexBox from '../helpers/SimpleFlexBox';
import MultiLineInput from '../widgets/MultiLineInput';

type SpecialInputFieldPropType = {
}

type SpecialInputFieldStateType = {
    length: number;
}

export default class SpecialInputField extends React.Component<SpecialInputFieldPropType, SpecialInputFieldStateType> {

    constructor (props: SpecialInputFieldPropType) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <SimpleFlexBox/>
        );
    }

}
```

I am using React.js with TypeScript & ES6 classes to make a Component.

At `<SimpleFlexBox/>` the WebStorm IDE prompts with the following error;

`Expected >`
'expression expected'

I have used this convention successfully before without this issue - is it possible to tell from the code above what could be causing the issue?

Comment: which file extension do you use?

Comment: ...Thank you. This is not the first time that has happened.

Comment: Changing the extension from `.ts` to `tsx` resolved the issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the extension from `.ts` to `.tsx` resolved the issue